# mySQL database is not fetching data in React

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

[image]I am using React for my front end. MySQL as my database, Node JS EXpress JS for the backend and Axios as my middleware. Every thing is working fine , the admin page is working fine , the forms are sending data to the database. The problem is that I have created a page to show the messages from the database and for some reason the database is not fetching the data from the table I want. I get the error data.map() is not a function , because the data state is not being set in the axios.get() function. I have provided the code below:

Messages.js

```
import React , {useEffect , useState} from 'react';
import MessageCard from './MessageCard';
import ax from 'axios';
import './Messages.css';




function Messages()
{


    const [data , setData] = useState({});

    useEffect(()=>{


        ax.get('http://localhost:3001/server/message').then((response)=>{

            if(response)
            {
                setData(response.data);
            }

            console.log(response.data);

            response.data.map((element)=>{console.log(element.ID)});

        });

        console.log(1);





    } , [setData])


    return(
        <>

<div id="messageMain">
             {data.map((element)=>{return <MessageCard fullName = {element.FullName} em = {element.Email} no = {element.PhoneNumber} msg = {element.Message} />})}
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Messages;
```

index.js (Server File)

```
const myServer = require('express');
const db = require('mysql');
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const serverObj = myServer();
const cors = require('cors');



const database = db.createPool({
    host:'localhost',
    user:'root',
    password : 'apt-getinstall',
    database : 'unified_messages'
})

serverObj.use(myServer.json());
serverObj.use(cors());

serverObj.use(body_parser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

serverObj.post('/server/insert' , (req,res)=>{

    const FullName = req.body.FullName;
    const Email = req.body.Email;
    const PhoneNumber = req.body.PhoneNumber;
    const Message = req.body.Message;

    console.log(FullName);
    const insertData = 'INSERT INTO client (FullName , Email , PhoneNumber , Message) VALUES (?,?,?,?)';
    database.query(insertData , [FullName , Email ,PhoneNumber , Message ] , (err , result)=>{console.log(err)});
})


serverObj.get('/server/admin' , (req,res)=>{
    const Username = req.body.Username;
    const Password = req.body.Password;
    const getData = 'SELECT username , password FROM unified_admins;';
    var usernameD , passwordD;
    database.query(getData , (err,result)=>{ res.send(result)});
    


})

serverObj.get('/server/message' , (req,res)=>{


    const getData = 'SELECT * FROM client;';
    database.query(getData , (err,result)=>{ res.send(result); console.log(result); console.log(err);});
    


})

serverObj.listen(3001 , ()=>{console.log('Connected')} );
```

The network panel is shown below:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes , Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Landing from './Components/Landing';
import Home from './Components/Home';
import Services from './Components/Services';
import Particlesbg from './Components/Particlesbg';
import Aboutus from './Components/Aboutus';
import Work from './Components/Work';
import Contact from './Components/Contact';
import Admin from './Components/Admin';
import Messages from './Components/Messages';


function App() {


    return (
        <>

        <Particlesbg/>
        <Routes>

            <Route exact path = "/" element = {<Landing/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Home" element = {<Home/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/About" element = {<Aboutus/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Services" element = {<Services/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Contact" element = {<Contact/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Work" element = {<Work/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Admin" element = {<Admin/>} />
            <Route exact path = "/Messages" element = {<Messages/>} />
        </Routes>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Firstly, check that the data is actually being retrieved correctly in the chrome dev tools network pane and report back. We can't tell if this is a server problem or a front end problem as it stands.

Comment: @AdamThomas I have checked and found out that the data is being retrieved from the database. When I go to "http://localhost:3001/server/message" . It displays the fetched data but it is not going into the front-end.

Comment: Its worth noting that hitting the URL directly in the browser is not the same as checking the network pane in the chrome inspector on the tab your actual app is running, as the latter is subject to things like CORS, which could be the reason. Did you check there too?

Comment: @AdamThomas  The network panel is showing nothing at all I have uploaded A picture of network panel in the question above.

Comment: Thanks! Well that helps us -- the request is never made in the first place. Do you see your `console.log(1);` output on console?

Comment: Please note, you have to refresh after opening the network pane to see everything.

Comment: No, I don't see any output in the console.

Comment: Ok, do we even know if the `Messages` component is being mounted? I think we now need to dig deeper and need to see the component where `<Messages/>` is actually used.

Comment: okay, so now there is a bunch of stuff in the network panel after refreshing I have added it in the question

Comment: Ah ok, lets reset. Is the request in question there, and in the response pane, do you see everything?

Comment: Cool yeh I can see the request is not made. Going back to my previous comment, I think we now need to see how and where the Messages component is mounted wherever its uised.

Comment: It is used in App.js I have added the App.js code in the question

Comment: make sure `response.data` is an array, not an object

Comment: Oh, that fixed the problem , everything is working now Thanks a lot !

Comment: @AdamSaleem what exactly, and where, on the server? you might update the post

Comment: The component that was not being rendered before is now rendering because it  takes data from the data base. I was putting the response.data in the state "data" that was the being used as a prop for the MessageCard component. I had the data type of "data" set as an object where response.data was an array so I set the data type to array and the data started displaying on my webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `.map` is an array `[]` method you are trying to use on an object `{}`. you need to change that. You need change `useState({})` to `useState([])`.

After make sure your state is updated before trying to map it.

Here is a solution to insure there is items in your array.

```
 ax.get('http://localhost:3001/server/message').then((response)=>{

            if(response)
            {
                setData(response.data);
            }

            console.log(response.data);
            
            // Checks to see if there is an item in the array.
            if(data[0]){
              // Then map over array if item is in array
              response.data.map((element)=>{console.log(element.ID)});
            }

        });
```

Hope This helps :)